# Dashed border animation in css3 animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I saw this article http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/BorderAnimationSVG/

I want to add this in my WP blog. So that each new post div have this animation on its border. But problem is that its in SVG. Is there anyway i can make this animation work without using SVG and also i don't want to use javascript.

Lets say code is:

```css
.go {
  width: 900px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 8px dashed;
}
```

```html
<div class="go"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible with just pure CSS. However this will be pretty verbose solution with several wrapper containers, pseudo elements and CSS animations/transitions. But not very difficult.

Comment: can you **please** show an example

Comment: @Sarthakkiller: There is a simple example also possible with CSS but do you want the reverse border animation also? That is on hover on direction and reverse in another? Also do you need a dashed border or is a full solid border like in that demo good?

Comment: Yeah! i want nearest possible.@Harry

Answer (score 75, accepted):

This much is possible with CSS and is pretty simple when using multiple backgrounds and changing their positions using animations.

```css
.border {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, blue 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, blue 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(0deg, blue 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(0deg, blue 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x, repeat-y, repeat-y;
  background-size: 16px 4px, 16px 4px, 4px 16px, 4px 16px;
  background-position: 0px 0px, 212px 116px, 0px 116px, 216px 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: background-position 2s;
}
.border:hover{
    background-position: 212px 0px, 0px 116px, 0px 0px, 216px 116px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="border">Some text</div>
```

---

Here is a sample with continuous movement of the borders right from the page load.

```css
.border {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, blue 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, blue 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(0deg, blue 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(0deg, blue 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x, repeat-y, repeat-y;
  background-size: 15px 4px, 15px 4px, 4px 15px, 4px 15px;
  background-position: 0px 0px, 200px 100px, 0px 100px, 200px 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  animation: border-dance 4s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes border-dance {
  0% {
    background-position: 0px 0px, 300px 116px, 0px 150px, 216px 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 300px 0px, 0px 116px, 0px 0px, 216px 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="border">Some text</div>
```

Credits to [web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki) for helping to fix the slight distortion that was originally present at the end of each loop of the animation.

Comment: Yes @SarthakSharma. That is just the closest I thought that could be achieved. I am trying to see if it can be improved. Else will remove it.

Comment: @SarthakSharma: That was my final update. Continuous movement of the border can be achieved, but with it reverse movement will not happen and vice-versa (atleast for this answer).

Comment: Great can we make it continuous ?

Comment: By continuous you mean making the border move always as long as the hover is on? If yes, this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4cvus7z6/) is a sample that you could try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70446/discussion-between-sarthak-sharma-and-harry).

Comment: After setting this to width: auto it doesn't work anymore https://jsfiddle.net/8m40uwb9/

Comment: How to adjust this to a different height?

Comment: How well do the browsers implement this feature?

Answer (score 44):

based on answer of  [harry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2606013/harry)

this can animate all shapes  with all sizes

```css
   div {
margin: 10px;
}

.size1 {
background: black;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}

.size2 {
background: black;
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
}


.active-animation {
background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, silver 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, silver 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(0deg, silver 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(0deg, silver 50%, transparent 50%);
background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x, repeat-y, repeat-y;
background-size: 15px 2px, 15px 2px, 2px 15px, 2px 15px;
background-position: left top, right bottom, left bottom, right top;
animation: border-dance 1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes border-dance {
0% {
    background-position: left top, right bottom, left bottom, right top;
}

100% {
    background-position: left 15px top, right 15px bottom, left bottom 15px, right top 15px;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="size1 active-animation"></div>
<div class="size2 active-animation"></div>
```

Comment: This is a great solution, using `top` `bottom` `left` and `right`. Some of the other solutions have "hiccups" in the animation or different speeds for horizontal/vertical. This looks great!

Comment: Precisely what I was after, works like a charm!

Comment: Thanks ! I tried to achieve the same using percentages, but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 24):

Here's a way to do it without having to specify the size of the element you want the rotating border on:

```css
.rotating-border {
  width: max-content;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, purple 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, purple 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(0deg, purple 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(0deg, purple 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x, repeat-y, repeat-y;
  background-size: 15px 4px, 15px 4px, 4px 15px, 4px 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  animation: border-dance 4s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes border-dance {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 100% 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 100% 0, 0 100%, 0 0, 100% 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="rotating-border">Hello World</div>
```

Comment: Wish I'd scrolled down to this answer before recreating this myself 

Comment: how do you prevent the animation from 'jumping' after the 4 seconds?

Answer (score 12):

With pure CSS you can use [`repeating-linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient) to draw the dots on the background, set the [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) and on hover move the background.

Sample css code:

```
.animationBorder {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 12px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.animationBorder:hover .background {
  background-position: 100px 0;
}
.background, .content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.background {
  transition: 1200ms;
  background-color: black;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 10px, #ffffff 10px, #ffffff 20px);
  background-size: 30px;
}
.content {
  transition: 200ms;
  margin: 1px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Demo:

```css
.animationBorder {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 12px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.animationBorder:hover .background {
  background-position: 100px 0;
}
.background, .content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.background {
  transition: 1200ms;
  background-color: black;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 10px, #ffffff 10px, #ffffff 20px);
  background-size: 30px;
}
.content {
  transition: 200ms;
  margin: 1px;
  line-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<span class="animationBorder">
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="content">My post</div>
</span>
```

Comment: Although in my experience this isn't the most *cross browser compatible* solution, it works on chrome.

Comment: can i even make it continues. I mean without using hover

Comment: That is simply awesome and way better than my own answer.

Comment: @jbutler483 totally agree, is a proof of concept

Comment: @Harry I have this code in my toolbelt from a while, but is not totally mine!

Comment: @IrvinDominin: (Don't tell anybody) for those of us here it is your answer and your code :)

Comment: @IrvinDominin can it be continuous ?

Comment: If you don't specify a fixed width then the gradient will not be rotated

Answer (score 9):

Animating a pseudo-element worked better for my round button:

```css
.border {
    position: relative;
    border: 0;
    height: 4rem;
    width: 4rem;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.border:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px dashed limegreen;
  animation: rotate 20s linear infinite;
}
  
@keyframes rotate {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg) }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg) }
}
```

```html
<div class="border"> hello </div>
```

Answer (score 6):

This code is adapted from the answer written by @Harry, modified in response to the question posted by @dude, that will work for a div with any width and height.

```css
.box
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.dashed 
{
  background: 
    linear-gradient(90deg, blue 50%, transparent 50%),
    linear-gradient(0deg, blue 50%, transparent 50%),
    linear-gradient(90deg, blue 50%, transparent 50%),
    linear-gradient(0deg, blue 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-y, repeat-x, repeat-y;
  background-size: 15px 4px, 4px 15px, 15px 4px, 4px 15px;
  background-position: left top, right top, left bottom, left top;
  padding: 4px;
  animation: border-dance 4s infinite linear;
}
 
@keyframes border-dance 
{
  0%
  {
    background-position: left top, right top, right bottom, left bottom;
  }
  100% 
  {
    background-position: right top, right bottom, left bottom, left top;
  }
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vel volutpat ante, eu convallis turpis. Cras sit amet est diam. Suspendisse non lectus faucibus, egestas enim quis, feugiat sapien. Nulla pellentesque, risus sit amet ultrices congue, nisl
ante semper est, in tempor eros augue quis tellus. Morbi venenatis varius eros sit amet dapibus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed lobortis sit amet lacus quis tincidunt. Curabitur nibh ex,
imperdiet sit amet sem a, ornare vehicula ipsum. Quisque vitae dui dignissim, viverra enim et, porta risus. Pellentesque pharetra at neque eu efficitur.
<div class="box dashed"></div>
```

Comment: Nice Marching Ants effect :)

Comment: Doesn't work as intended I assume... Might want to update this answer

Answer (score 4):

This is only a quick example, but it's using pseudo effects to 'move' the border on a hover (note. keyframes would be more beneficial if you wanted to 'continue' the effect)

```css
.go {
  width: 900px;
  height: 200px;
  position:relative;
  border:8px dashed black;
}

.go:hover:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  top:-8px;
  left:-8px;
  border: 8px solid black;
  }

.go:hover:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  top:-8px;
  left:-8px;
  border: 8px dashed white;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="go">hover then 'unhover' to see effect</div>
```

---

## A better example

---

This might suit you better since, the animation would be easier to continue too:

```css
.bord {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.spinner {
  position: absolute;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  background: black;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
.go {
  position: absolute;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  background: white;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
}
.bord:hover .spinner {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bord">
  <div class="spinner"></div>
  <div class="go">hover me!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can i increase the dash space and make it look like the example