# How to create a dashed border that looks the same on all browsers?

Tags: html, css, border, css-shapes

I can make a single CSS dashed border, as shown below, but how would the top and side borders be made?

Yes, `border: dashed` would do it, but the problem is that the dash renders differently in Chrome, IE, FF, etc., so I am in search of a universal cross-browser style declaration with control over dash thickness, as well as spacing and length, and started out below with one border.

HTML:

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    height:95px;
    margin-top:6px;
    padding-top:10px;
}

.box:hover {
    color:#2200dd;
    height:101px;
    margin-top:0px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, currentColor 0%, currentColor 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%) repeat-x left top, left bottom;    
    background-size: 60px 6px;
}
```

Comment: Why not just use the CSS `border` property? http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp

Comment: @bnahin: That would not allow control over the size of the dashes or space in between them.

Comment: @Guessed: You would have to use multiple gradients and change the direction of the gradient (towards bottom) and the positioning of it (instead of `left top` and `left bottom`).

Comment: @Harry - I think that's what I am after - How would multiple gradients be declared?

Comment: @Guessed: Have a look at my snippet [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365839/dashed-border-animation-in-css3-animation/28366181#28366181). Not posting an answer because it would look like a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the `border` property?

```
.box:hover {
    border: 5px dashed #2200dd;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tph7515v/

Comment: Yes, this is correct, but it is my fault for not having clarified that I need control over dash spacing and length, so I updated my question and title to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the border property. CSS:

```
border: 5px dashed black;
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct, but it is my fault for not having clarified that I need control over dash spacing and length, so I updated my question and title to reflect this.

Answer (score -1):

A simple `border` CSS would already achieve your desired output

```
.box {
    height:95px;
    margin-top:6px;
    padding-top:10px;
}

.box:hover {
    border : 10px dashed blue
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct, but it is my fault for not having clarified that I need control over dash spacing and length, so I updated my question and title to reflect this.