# Marching ant border using a GIF

Tags: css, border-image

I know there's a way to do marching ants with linear-gradients but it eats a huge amount of CPU (about 10% for each one). I am trying to make an alt solution but find `border-image-slice` confusing.

Here is the outdated tutorial I'm using: http://www.chrisdanford.com/blog/2014/04/28/marching-ants-animated-selection-rectangle-in-css/

I've removed the obsolete css but I'm not sure how to slice the image so that the ants are marching. The tut says:

> We’ll start with a 10px x 10px animated gif that is composed of nine
>   tiles: 1×1 in the corners, 1×8 or 8×1 on the edges, and 8×8 in the
>   center.

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}

.marching {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-image-source: url('https://i.imgsafe.org/e5bc19b03a.gif');
  border-image-slice: 1;
  border-image-repeat: stretch stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="box marching"></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Seen this one, the 2:nd sample: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28366181/2827823

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background should repeat, not stretch. Is this what you're going for?

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}

.marching {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-image-source: url('https://i.imgsafe.org/e5bc19b03a.gif');
  border-image-slice: 1;
  border-image-repeat: repeat repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box marching"></div>
```

Comment: Yep! thanks for some reason I checked the spec and didn't see repeat and thought it had been changed to stretch

Comment: Link to the `.gif` is broken.

Answer (score 2):

Here is CSS version I found, how does it compare with the others when it comes to CPU usage?

```css
body { background: green; }
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
  background: black;
}
.box * {
  position: absolute;
}
.box div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.box div:nth-child(1) { transform: rotate(   0deg ); }
.box div:nth-child(2) { transform: rotate(  90deg ); }
.box div:nth-child(3) { transform: rotate( 180deg ); }
.box div:nth-child(4) { transform: rotate( 270deg ); }
.box i {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 200%;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed white;
}
.box i {
  animation: marching 4s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes marching {
  from { transform: translateX( -50% ); }
  to   { transform: translateX(   0% ); }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div><i></i></div>
  <div><i></i></div>
  <div><i></i></div>
  <div><i></i></div>
</div>
```

Src: https://jsfiddle.net/desandro/zm7Et/

Comment: Nice, very rough/quick estimate it uses 3-4% which is decent, animation looks better too

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why you're not using a canvas?

The Canvas element has a lineDashOffset property that is often used for marching ant effects:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineDashOffset

If you're planning on using a GIF it looks as though scaling isn't something you're worried about, so maybe a canvas might be a better way to do it. Buffer-canvases might also be used to improve performance.

Comment: Thanks, I may look into to that but the gif/css solution is an easy drop in replacement for now (for an image cropping area that's a div)