# Would this type of animation be usable?

Tags: html, css, animation

I've made an animation where a border is animated. But in reality, it's just an illusion.

This the HTML

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: verdana;
}

.container {
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 15%;
 left: 35%;
}

.outer-block {
 width: 30vw;
 height: 30vh;
 background-color: white;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.inner-block {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-flex;
 width: 28vw;
 height: 27vh;
 background-color: white;
 top: -39.5vh;
 z-index: 2000;
}

.block-1 {
 height: 50vh;
 width: 5vw;
 background-color: black;
 z-index: 10;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 5vw;
 margin-top: -9vh;
}

.block-2 {
 top: 10vh;
 height: 50vh;
 width: 5vw;
 background-color: black;
 z-index: 10;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 10vw;
 margin-top: -9vh;

}

.outer-block:hover .block-1 {
 transform: rotate(1440deg);
 transition-duration: 12s;
 animation-name: colorchange;

}

.outer-block:hover .block-2 {
 transform: rotate(1440deg);
 transition-duration: 12s;
 animation-name: colorchange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="outer-block">
   <div class="block-1"></div>
   <div class="block-2"></div>

    <div class="inner-block"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So basically, I'm making multiple shapes on top of each other. With overflow hidden and placing the animated parts between buttons, I can control border animations (which aren't really borders) much more, since I can control every shapes path.

My only worry is that it's going to show it's weakness somewhere along the line. SHould I keep doing stuff like this, or is this better avoided?

https://codepen.io/dario-sanchez-martinez/pen/LgZMZV

Comment: check this for some magic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365839/dashed-border-animation-in-css3-animation

Comment: But then you can only animate it in a few different ways. Border styling seems very limited.