# Rotation dashed border js

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I want to create a rotating dashed border(on hover/onmouseover) but my div's height and width are not the same so this excludes some solutions. Also, I'm working with JavaScript because I want the other div to change the color of his border too. Here is my current code:

```js
let borderSlika1 = document.getElementById("levi");
let borderSlika2 = document.getElementById("desni");

function borderL() {
  borderSlika1.style.border = "3px dashed #00FF20";
  borderSlika1.style.borderRadius = "50px";
  borderSlika2.style.border = "3px dashed #FF6A17";
  borderSlika2.style.borderRadius = "50px";

}

function borderNoneL() {
  borderSlika1.style.border = "3px dashed transparent";
  borderSlika2.style.border = "3px dashed transparent";
}

function borderD() {
  borderSlika2.style.border = "3px dashed #00FF20";
  borderSlika2.style.borderRadius = "50px";
  borderSlika1.style.border = "3px dashed #FF6A17";
  borderSlika1.style.borderRadius = "50px";

}

function borderNoneD() {
  borderSlika1.style.border = "3px dashed transparent";
  borderSlika2.style.border = "3px dashed transparent";
}
```

```html
<div id="levi" onmouseover="borderL()" onmouseleave="borderNoneL()">
  <img src="slike/slikaTisk.png" class="izbira"></div>
<div id="desni" onmouseover="borderD()" onmouseleave="borderNoneD()">
  <img src="slike/slikaZacimbe.png" class="izbira"></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dashed border animation in css3 animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365839/dashed-border-animation-in-css3-animation)

Comment: This won’t work since I use “vh” for div’s height so the height is always changing (depending on user’s screen height) or will it?  I ‘m not familiar to this type of styling.