# What's the correct way of implementing animated border bottom?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, linear-gradients

Should it be a separate div? I can't figure out how to apply this to a div that already has some content.

```css
.dashed-line {
  height: 3px;
  width: 700px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, red 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, red 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-size: 0px 0px, 15px 4px, 4px 0px, 4px 0px;
  background-position: 0px 0px, 200px 100px, 0px 100px, 200px 0px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  animation: border-dance 7s infinite linear;

}
@keyframes border-dance {
  0% {
    background-position: 300px 0px, 0px 116px, 0px 0px, 216px 150px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0px 0px, 300px 116px, 0px 150px, 216px 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="dashed-line"></div>
```

Comment: it's a background, so you can put content inside exactly like the code you are using from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365839/dashed-border-animation-in-css3-animation

Comment: @TemaniAfif I tried to experiment with it but it always adds some redundant padding that I can't get rid off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an easier syntax:

```css
.box {
  --p:10px; /* width of the pattern */
  --w:4px;  /* width of the gap inside the pattern */
  --h:3px;  /* height of line */

  padding: 8px;
  font-size:20px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(90deg, red calc(100% - var(--w)), transparent 0)
    0 100% / var(--p) var(--h) repeat-x;
  animation: move 0.3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  to {
    background-position: var(--p) 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  some text
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the kind of situation the [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) `::before` and `::after` are particularly suited for.

Basically, they allow you to add elements to your page that aren't actual "content". It can either be some textual decoration through the `content` css property. Or you can leave that property as an empty string `''` and just take advantage of the fact that you have a "pseudo-div" added to your node.

```css
span {
  position: relative;
}
span::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, red 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, red 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-size: 0px 0px, 15px 4px, 4px 0px, 4px 0px;
  background-position: 0px 0px, 200px 100px, 0px 100px, 200px 0px;
  animation: border-dance 7s infinite linear;

}
@keyframes border-dance {
  0% {
    background-position: 300px 0px, 0px 116px, 0px 0px, 216px 150px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0px 0px, 300px 116px, 0px 150px, 216px 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<span> hello i have some content </span>
```