# How to animate a black and white dashed border like a "Photoshop selection"?

Tags: css

When I select something with one of the selection tools in Photoshop, an animated *streaming* black-and-white colored dashed stroke (border) surrounds the selection.

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _|
```

Is there an CSS-only way to recreate this border style?

Perhaps use the below GIF as a stroke's background image?

→ [image: selection animation photoshop]

I figured this CSS is not possible:

```
.selected {
  border: 1px solid url("selection.gif");
}
```

I tried a black dashed border on top of a white solid border, however could not find a way to animate or offset somehow.

**Update:**

I have been made aware of some borders that are dashed and stream. However these are single coloured, and have open 'empty' spaced gaps between dashes. I'm looking for a Photoshop selection style version:

white dash → black dash → white dash → black dash

Instead of:

Black dash → empty space → black dash → empty space

Like so:

[image]

**Update 2**

[This code-pen](https://codepen.io/stg/pen/YGRpkJ) by mister *St.G* from Minneapolis comes close, however is a single coloured version with gaps.

Comment: It's close! however this would result in a one colour dashed version and not a two coloured (black and white) Photoshop selection style variant.

Comment: @Jordy I think you have enough information to figure out a solution. Just change the colors :) 

Hint: `#fff` is white and `#000` is black. The code-pen you linked actually has what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

> It's close! however this would result in a one colour dashed version
> and not a two coloured (black and white) Photoshop selection style
> variant.

You can use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28366181/1573267) and simply just change colors as @chojnicki and @Pablo already have said in comments.

```css
body{ background-color:blue; }
.border {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, black 50%, white 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, black 50%, white 50%), linear-gradient(0deg, black 50%, white 50%), linear-gradient(0deg, black 50%, white 50%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x, repeat-y, repeat-y;
  background-size: 15px 4px, 15px 4px, 4px 15px, 4px 15px;
  background-position: 0px 0px, 200px 100px, 0px 100px, 200px 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  animation: border-dance 4s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes border-dance {
  0% {
    background-position: 0px 0px, 300px 116px, 0px 150px, 216px 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 300px 0px, 0px 116px, 0px 0px, 216px 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="border">Some text</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

What I can infer from your post is that you want to have a dashed border.
Here's what to do:

```
#bordered-image {
  border: dashed 4px #000;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: OP want to animate the border